# Regex Teradata Question to identify amount in the fields

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

| ID | COLUMN_1 | COLUMN_2 | COLUMN_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | FEE $8 | NO FEE | UNPAID FEE $18. |
| 2 | UNPAID FEE | $12 | ACCOUNT_FEE $12. |
| 3 | OD FEE 2 * $4 $8 | FEE $9 | ACCOUNT_FEE $8. |

I have a table like the above and I need to separate different fees that are in different column in teradata. So the output for above should be

| ID | FEE | UNPAID_FEE | ACCOUNT_FEE | OD_FEE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | $8 | $18 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | $0 | $12 | 12 | 0 |
| 3 | $9. | $0. | $8 | 8 |

Essentially fees could be in different columns I need to find ways to separate them.
Also there could be other numbers as well like in OD fee row 3. But I just want the final OD fee there.

Answer (score 0):

This is really really ugly.  But based on the assumption that the first "word" is what you want to use for your output columns, and the last "word" is the value for those columns, you can use `STRTOK` to get the first word, and `INSTR` with `SUBSTRING` to get the last one.  Then finally, you can use case expressions to build your desired output.

```
select
id,
case
    when col1_type = 'FEE' then col1_val
    when col2_type = 'FEE' then col2_val
    when col3_type = 'FEE' then col3_val
else 0 end as FEE,
...
from (
select
id,
strtok(col1,' ',1) as col1_type,
substr(col1, instr(col1, ' ', -1) +2) as col1_val,
strtok(col2,' ',1) as col2_type,
substr(col2, instr(col2, ' ', -1) +2) as col2_val,
strtok(col3,' ',1) as col3_type,
substr(col3, instr(col3, ' ', -1) +2) as col3_val

from
<your table> ) t
```

I wouldn't be surprised if this falls apart pretty quickly. That is a really messed up way to store data.